# on JBOSS EAP 7.3 unable to load mariadb JDBC driver on managed domain on full profile

Tags: mariadb, jboss7.x

i'm having problem on adding mariadb jdbc driver on managed domain with profile=full--> [following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNytt.png)

my current configuration

[module defined for mariadb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIN9E.png)

This is the file jar  i've used
mariadb-java-client-2.7.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

When you want to configure the data source in domain mode then make sure you install the JDBC Driver as a module on each Host Controller.

As there are no management instruments available on the Host Controllers, you need to execute the module add command on each Host Controller in disconnected mode:

e.g.

disconnected /] module add --name=org.mariadb --resources=mariadb-java-client-2.7.1.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api